# What is the difference between breakpoint and max-width, what is the best use case for them?

Tags: sass

```
 .about-wrapper {
       width: 100%;
       @media screen and(max-width: $large) {
         width: 600px;
         height: 338px;
         margin-left: -300px;
         margin-top: -190px;
    }
  }
```

vs

```
  .about-wrapper{
      width: 100%;
      @include breakpoint($large) {
         width: 600px;
         height: 338px;
         margin-left: -300px;
         margin-top: -190px;
    }
  }
```

Is there a proper way to use max-width? 
Does one perform better than another? I am trying to understand the pros/cons of the two.

Answer (score 1):

They are just SASS vs CSS way of writing things. @include breakpoint is compiled to css3 @media. In your case:

```
$large = 100px;

@include breakpoint($large) {
    ...
}
```

is compiled to:

```
@media (min-width: 100px) {
    ...
}
```

If you wanna set the breakpoint on max-width instead, do this:

```
$large = max-width 100px;

@include breakpoint($large) {
    ...
}
```

which will compile to:

```
@media (max-width: 100px) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoint is a mixin from some SASS library. I bet you are using [Breakpoint Sass](http://breakpoint-sass.com/). This mixin compiles to @media statements, so it's not that one is better than the other but different ways to manage media queries.